# Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

VS code is not able to find definitions in the project from work.

Trying to setup VS code to easily search through the code, and for the most part the definitions do work.  The problem here is that some definitions don't work, and when that happens it throws the error below.

The specific file this runs into is a java file, and other java files do work find.

Followed the guide in "https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java" to get vs code setup, as well as all java packages, and system environments for oracle and maven.

Just trying to find out what I am missing.  Unable to provide any code from the project as it is for work.

```
[2018-07-17 17:08:44.217] [renderer1] [error] Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
at asHoverContent (C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\redhat.java-0.28.0\node_modules\vscode-languageclient\lib\protocolConverter.js:99:26)
at asHover (C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\redhat.java-0.28.0\node_modules\vscode-languageclient\lib\protocolConverter.js:132:31)
at propagateAslWrapper (C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.9.2\node_modules\async-listener\index.js:502:23)
at C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.9.2\node_modules\async-listener\glue.js:188:31
at C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.9.2\node_modules\async-listener\index.js:539:70
at C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.9.2\node_modules\async-listener\glue.js:188:31
at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Since you are seeing an error, you should report this against the java extension

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This ended up being a poorly setup environment, my mistake.